# Accessing elements in a std::string with pointers

Tags: c++, c++14

How can I access individual elements in a std::string with pointers? Is it possible without type casting to a const char *?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    // I'm trying to do this...
    string str = "This is a string";
    cout << str[2] << endl;

    // ...but by doing this instead
    string *p_str = &str;
    cout << /* access 3rd element of str with p_str */ << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So you want to access the third element of a string through a pointer?

Comment: It's pretty much the same as accessing any other class object by a pointer. All standard ways apply.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. Call the `operator[]` function explicitly:

   ```
   std::cout << p_str->operator[](2) << '\n';
   ```

   Or use the `at` function

   ```
   std::cout << p_str->at(2) << '\n';
   ```

   Both of these are *almost* equivalent.
2. Or dereference the pointer to get the object, and use normal indexing:

   ```
   std::cout << (*p_str)[2] << '\n';
   ```

Either way, you need to dereference the pointer. Through the "arrow" operator `->` or with the direct dereference operator `*` doesn't matter.